# How to set up a cron job to run every 10 minutes?

Tags: scripts, python, cron

I have a python script, and i'd like to make it run every 10 minutes, how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

- Make the script executable by:

  ```
  chmod u+x /path/to/script.py
  ```

  Note that, you need a shebang (i.e. indicate interpreter in the first line of the script), for `python2`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python2
  ```

  For `python3`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  ```
- Open your cron table by

  ```
  crontab -e
  ```
- Add the following `cron` entry:

  ```
  */10 * * * * /path/to/script.py
  ```

---

Note that, if the script is not executable you can indicate the interpreter on the go:

- For `python2`:

  ```
  */10 * * * * /usr/bin/env python2 /path/to/script.py
  ```
- For `python3`:

  ```
  */10 * * * * /usr/bin/env python3 /path/to/script.py
  ```

Comment: Can i do this with .sh files too? I'd like to combine 3 scripts into one.

Comment: @NikoCodey Yes, you can..check my edits too..

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `cron`, you could also call your script in an infinite loop with a delay of 10 minutes.

If you want to launch the script again *10 minutes after the previous instance exited*, use this:

```
while true ; do /PATH/TO/SCRIPT.PY ; sleep 10m ; done
```

However, if you want to launch the script *every 10 minutes on the clock*, no matter how long the last instance was running (or whether it still is running), you must execute the script in background and sleep in parallel by replacing the `;` with an `&`:

```
 while true ; do /PATH/TO/SCRIPT.PY & sleep 10m ; done
```